# Porting to ARM processor - dependancies

Tags: arm

Am attempting to port some code to a Debian install on an ARM processor. Am having trouble finding 'libmygcc.a' - is this a compiled file or a library I need to install? I have it on a linux(x86) box but am not clear where it originated.

OpenSSL is next. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libmygcc.a is a library for mysql, so you would have to compile mysql for your ARM target